# Meteor - What is the typical size of mongodb document?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

What is the typical size of a document in a collection with around 10 - 15 textfields? How can I check its size locally?

I'm thinking of deploying the db of my app in compose.io. But I'm not sure if 1GB is big enough. I have an estimate of 1000 users and around 25 collections (all text).

Thanks,

Comment: How long is a piece of string? There is no "typical" size and mostly because we have no idea what you are "typically" storing. There are ways to work out a general "average" size though from your own data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command `db.collection.stats()` it will return the statistics about each collection. Have a look [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/). You could then change the display by adding

```
db.collection.stats({ scale : 1024 })
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation the BSON document size is 16MB. you can follow the link for more details - https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON

Comment: More of a comment with just a link  an answer. Also not what the OP is asking.